# Inherit UIViewController class and XIB

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

I'm developing an iOS 4 application and I have developed some classes that I want to use in others projects.

One of this classes, called `MapViewController`, is a UIViewController subclass. This class uses a XIB file that I've created with interface builder.

I'm wondering if a use `MapViewController` in another project as a super class from a new class, **How can I use it associated XIB?**

I want to reuse `MapViewController` and its XIB, but I don't know if I have to do something special with the XIB file.

I don't know how to explain this. If you need more details, please tell me.

**UPDATE:**

I want to create a new class that inherit from `MapViewController`, like this:

```
...
@interface NewMapViewController : MapViewController {

...
```

And, now if I want to continue using the same XIB (the one from `MapViewController`), **what must I do?**

Comment: Let me try to understand, you want to be able to use your MapViewController and his XIB, but if you need some special behavior you don't want to use the XIB?

Comment: It's not clear what is the exact problem.

Comment: Sorry. I've just updated my question with more details.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to inherit from the view controller?

Answer (score 7):

Since you are gonna inherit from `MapViewController`, your `MapViewController` becomes the super class. And you also have MapViewController.xib. It seems pretty straightforward to me if you use the initializer for `NewMapViewController`

**NewMapViewController.m**

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    NSLog(@"Subclass initWithNibName called");
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```

Initialize your NewMapViewContoller like:

```
//Nib of super class is MapViewController
NewMapViewController *nmapController = [[NewMapViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MapViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

Comment: No it doesn't. I tried. In fact, initWithNibName is never called.

Comment: @JimThio I have edited my answer. I tested this one and it works for me. Try it and let me know.